# What are all different (non-isomorphic) field structures on $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, real-numbers

We know that $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ forms a field under addition and multiplication defined as $(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$ ; $(a,b)*(c,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc)$ ; is there any other way to make $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ into a field non-isomorphic to this usual field ?

Comment: What you're asking is to list all the fields with cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$. There are lots of those.

Comment: Do you have any restrictions? Because if you just want a field structure on the _set_ $\Bbb R^2$ then any field $F$ of the same cardinality has a (set) bijection $\Bbb R^2$, which gives a field structure.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are bijections between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$, and thus we can take any bijection $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ and declare it a field isomorphism.  That is, it forms a field with addition
$$ (a,b)+(c,d)=f(f^{-1}(a,b)+f^{-1}(c,d))$$
where the additive identity is $f(0)$, and multiplication
$$ (a,b)\cdot (c,d)=f(f^{-1}(a,b)\cdot f^{-1}(c,d))$$
where the multiplicative identity is $f(1)$.

These are all isomorphic (being isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$), but not to the normal field structure on $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$, since the latter is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: But they are all isomorphic.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, but not to the normal field structure on $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: But the question explicitly said "non-isomorphic".

Comment: @AsafKaragila I read the question as saying "non-isomorphic to the usual field structure on $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$".  In this sense, I provided such an example, since $\mathbb{R}$ with its usual field structure is not isomorphic to the usual field structure on $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I think that you're being too literal with this. But sure, let's wait to hear from the OP.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Honestly, if it bothers you so much, I'll just delete the answer.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't see how Hayden is beeing too literal. His answer clearly shows that at least two field structures are possible: one isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, the other to $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila To qualify my above comment a little more (for I can see it coming off as stand-off-ish), if you believe strongly enough that this answer is not what the OP is looking for, then I'll happily delete the answer. (for I could be missing something)

Comment: @Dan: By showing that you have uncountably many ways to be isomorphic to $\Bbb R$, rather than to $\Bbb C$, you don't really have uncountably many *different* field structures. You only have two. Last time I checked, two is not uncountable! **Hayden**: No need to delete it, if I were offended, I'd have made a note of it. I just feel that it somewhat misses the intention of the question when you say that these are uncountably many structures, and not just one in different guises.

Comment: @AsafKaragila That is fair, and I've already edited the answer in order to better reflect those facts (i.e. that the uncountability I mentioned implied there were uncountably-many non-isomorphic field structures; I had mentioned this more to point out that there was quite a lot of bijections to choose from, rather than having anything to do with the field structures themselves).

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do it while preserving addition as it is.

Note that if $F$ is any field of characteristics $0$ and cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ then as a vector space over $\Bbb Q$, $F$ and $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb{R\times R}$ are isomorphic. So we can transport the multiplicative structure from $F$ to $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb{R\times R}$ while preserving addition.

So really you're asking how many non-isomorphic fields of characteristics $0$ there are on a set of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$. Some non-isomorphic examples are $\Bbb R$, the different $p$-adic fields, any transcendental extension of $\Bbb R$ by at most $2^{\aleph_0}$ transcendental elements; any subfield of $\Bbb R$ of the right cardinality, $\Bbb C$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want $\mathbb{R}$ to be a sub-field of the field $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, the answer is no. To see that, note that $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, and that it is the only possible algebraic extension of $\mathbb{R}$. In other words, once you extend $\mathbb{R}$ by a new number which is algebraic over $\mathbb{R}$, you automatically get something isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$.